# Cannot understand this error in this simple C program

Tags: c

I cannot figure out why when I execute this program, it keeps telling me that the code "salary = 40 * RATE + (hours-40) * OVERTIME_RATE;" in the if statement is "expression result unused". 
Please tell me what is wrong with it. Thank you soooo much.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define RATE 15.0;
#define OVERTIME_RATE 25.0;

int main(void)
{
  int emp_no;
  double hours, salary;

  printf("Employee Number: ");
  scanf("%d", &emp_no);
  printf("Enter the hours worked this week: ");
  scanf("%lf", &hours);

  if (hours <= 40.0){
     salary = hours*RATE;
  }else {salary = 40 * RATE + (hours-40) * OVERTIME_RATE;}

  printf("Pay of Employee %d is S$%8.2f.\n", emp_no, salary);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Remove the `';'` from the end of your `#define` lines -- the warnings will go away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is wrong

```
#define RATE 15.0;
```

The preprocessor works by textual substitution, so each time you mention `RATE`, is is replaced by `15.0;`, but you want it to be replaced by `15.0`.

Therefore you should write:

```
#define RATE 15.0
```

The same applies to `OVERTIME_RATE` of course.

Result of the substitution with your macro definitions:

```
{salary = 40 * 15.0; + (hours-40) * 25.0;;}
```

Which is the same as

```
{
  salary = 40 * 15.0;
  + (hours-40) * 25.0;;    // this line contains just an expression
                           // that is evaluated but not used, hence the warning
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Preprocessor macros aren't really a part of the core C language, as such they have different syntactic rules. Like for example they are terminated by the end of the line and not by a semicolon.

Also macros are basically copy-pasted into the code where they are used, which leads to your statement

```
salary = 40 * RATE + (hours-40) * OVERTIME_RATE;
```

really is

```
salary = 40 * 15.0; + (hours-40) * 25.0;;
```

Now it's easy to see what the problem is.

To solve your problem just remove the semicolons from the macro definitions.

Comment: Yep. The result of the legal expression `+ (hours-40) * 25.0` is not used.

Answer (score -2):

So, I tried running your program on an online compiler, exactly the way you wrote, it's working fine. Here's a screenshot.

[image: ScreenShot]

Mind sharing, what happened in yours?

EDIT: Found the problem in your code `#define` never ends with a semi-colon, ever so the updated code is running well.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define RATE 15.0
#define OVERTIME_RATE 25.0

int main(void){
  int emp_no;
  double hours, salary;

  printf("Employee Number: ");
  scanf("%d", &emp_no);
  printf("Enter the hours worked this week: ");
  scanf("%lf", &hours);

  if (hours <= 40.0){
     salary = hours*RATE;
  }
  else{
      salary=40 * RATE + (hours-40) * OVERTIME_RATE;
  }

  printf("Pay of Employee %d is S$%8.2f.\n", emp_no, salary);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: When you `#define RATE 15.0;` (note the trialing `';'`) the `else {salary = 40 * RATE` is all that is evaluated as the 1st line in the `else` clause leaving `(hours-40) * OVERTIME_RATE;` as the next line which is a *Statement Without Effect*. (I'm not your downvote)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Oh thank you for pointing that part out, I will be editing the answer now.